# Teradata Arithmetic operations

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

In Teradata when computing a percentage (see example below), I get 0 as an answer because Terada rounds results based on the number of decimal places the number have. to my knowledge I have found 2 possible solution to avoid the zero value return.

1- define the decimal number in table with a larger scale value. e.g decimal(18,4) instead of decimal(18,2)
2- cast the first arithmetic operation that occurs to a decimal number with a larger scale value. e.g.  select (cast(2.0 as decimal(10,6)) / 10.0) * 100;

has anyone encounter this problem before and what is the solution you went with to solve the problem? thank you in advance.

these are the actual values and the correct answer should be 0.25

```
   select ((28.97 + 28.97) / (11586.87 + 11586.87)) * 100
          ,(cast((28.97 + 28.97) as decimal(20,4)) / (11586.87 + 11586.87)) * 100
          ,((cast(28.97  as decimal(18,4)) + 28.97) /   (11586.87   + 11586.87))
          ,(100 * (28.97 + 28.97) / (11586.87 + 11586.87))
          ,(28.97 + 28.97) , (11586.87 + 11586.87);
```

Comment: Rule of thumb for limited-precision arithmetic in general (not just Teradata) is to postpone division as long as possible: `(100 * (28.97 + 28.97)) / (11586.87 + 11586.87)`.

Comment: If you are going to CAST, consider using FLOAT or NUMBER for calculations and then CAST the result to the desired DECIMAL scale.

Comment: Why postponing division as long as possible is the rule of thumb? in Terada the only thing that multiplication does is that adds the scale places of the two numbers when creating the output. e.g. select 1.00 * 1.0; outputs 1.000

Comment: The general question for _fixed-precision arithmetic_ (which is essentially integer arithmetic with scaling) is what should be the scale of the quotient. That's where rounding / loss of precision comes into play. There are many references available with more detail.